# Can't send mail in cakePHP3 from Godaddy

Tags: php, email, smtp, cakephp-3.0

I'm using Gourmet/Email and unable to send mail on Gadaddy from zoho.com hosted account, although everything was working well locally. My transport config is as follow :

```
'default' => [
        'transport' => 'default',
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.zoho.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'username' => 'address',
        'password' => 'pass',
        'emailFormat' => 'both',
        'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),
        'className' => 'Smtp'
        
    ],
```

I'm getting such a response :

> Connection refused
>
> Cake\Network\Exception\SocketException

Can somebody help me fix this ?

Comment: First you have to check whether email service is active in hosting environment or not?

Comment: I've contacted GoDaddy's customer service. There's any problem, they assure me mail service is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed `Smtp` into `Mail` for `className` as found [here](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.2.7/app/Config/email.php.default) :

```
'default' => [
    'transport' => 'default',
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.zoho.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'username' => 'address',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'emailFormat' => 'both',
    'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),
    'className' => 'Mail'

],
```

And it's fixed.

Comment: can u please elaborate. i am trying to send mails form my cakephp 3 application which is placed in godaddy server. Please help me.

Comment: Hi, @waseem, as mentioned in the question, I use Gourmet/Email plug-in (can be found on Github) and in the config (config/app.php) you need to place this piece of code. Reminder: you can't use smtp on godaddy if you're using another mail hosting service than their own.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i m using godaddys smtp outgoing server link for sending emails, also i have created a new email addres associated to my godaddy domain. Is it that even now i cannot send emails from godaddy?

Comment: If you're using Godaddy's mail hosting service, there may not be a problem. However, use 'className' => 'Mail' and I hope everything'll be well. With this, sending can be delayed.